# I put stuff in my git repository that I shouldn't have

Tags: git, version-control

I am a new user to git, a new user to content tracking/source control in general actually. I started using git about 6 months ago and have really grown to like it.

Foolishly I have been tracking my complete projects, including lib directories which includes each project's needed libraries. Some of these are libraries that I cannot distribute. I do intend to share my git repo with coworkers and some of my projects may become FOSS at some point. Being able to share my git repo is important to me.

What's the way to proceed out of this mess without losing my history?

Also, it's annoying because as you know, some versions of software require certain versions of libraries or they won't compile. If I cannot put the library in the git repository, this means I may have to do manual tinkering just to get a specific commit version of my programs to work again. In other words, this is a huge hassle.

Am I misunderstanding something about using git? This seems like a gigantic issue.

EDIT: I can easily imagine scenarios where large projects get contaminated by commits of non-free material. And I can imagine the problem going undetected for a long time so this seems like an Achilles Heel for distributed content tracking. I also think having to manually find and use perhaps dozens of libraries each time you want to investigate some small change to be completely infeasible. Thus this leaves git in practice only capable of being used on totally free projects. Am I wrong?

Comment: FWIW when your program requires particular versions of libraries, usually you give those version specifications in a README file or something but leave it to other people to actually obtain the libraries on their own. You don't need to distribute everything required to run your program.

Comment: You can use [git-filter-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) to edit your history, but be careful as this is a complicated command.

Answer (score 2):

First, dependency tracking.  If the libraries are open source, including them as submodules could help with keeping them updated.  However, since that isn't what this sounds like you need them out.  If they can be obtained easily, free but not open, I've used Maven in the past with pretty good success.   http://maven.apache.org/  I've found it doesn't work particularly well in Windows though.

For your git problem, try this:

1. Checkout the commit where the libraries were added.
2. Create a branch from that commit, i.e. whoops.
3. git rm -rf libs
4. Add libs to .gitignore
5. git cherry-pick ..most_recent_commit
6. If this is now the version of the project you want:

   1. Yay!  Continue.
   2. Shoot . . . good thing you're on a branch!
7. Checkout master
8. git reset --hard commit_from_other_branch
9. Commit
10. Force a push, the old master will be orphaned.  git push -f

Be very careful how you do this, you could seriously mess up your repository.  This won't completely remove the reference the libraries either, since that first commit will still have the references to it.  Someone may have another method that uses the patch facility that might be better. . .